# PrivateRouter does not work as well in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm at the beginning of learning React JS. In my project I need to create two routes, one for user authenticated and one that needs to redirect to login page.

I've created this structure, using React Router. This is the container of route:

```
export const history = createHistory();

class AppContainer extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
    this.props.checkUserExist();
}


render() {

    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Welcome} exact={true}/>
                <PrivateRoute path="/friends"  component={Friends}/>
                <PublicRoute path="/login"  component={Login}/>
                <PrivateRoute path="/loves" component={Loves}/>
                <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

}


  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {    
     checkUserExist: () => dispatch(checkUser())     
    };
};

export default connect(undefined,mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer);
```

These are action:

```
export const checkUser = () => (dispatch) => {

dispatch({
    type: CHECKING_USER,
    payload: {
       loading:true,
       isAuth:false
    }
});

from(axios.get('https://mysite.private.com/userExist', {
    withCredentials: true
})).subscribe((result) => {

    console.log('result:', result);

    result.data == null
        ? dispatch({
            type: USER_NOT_EXIST,
            payload: {
                isAuth: false,
                loading:false
            }
        })

        : dispatch({
            type: USER_EXIST,
            payload: {
                isAuth: true,
                user:result.data,
                loading: false
            }
        });

}, (error) => dispatch({
    type: USER_CHECKING_ERROR,
    payload: {
        loading: false,
        isAuth:false,
        error
    }
 }));
};
```

and reducer:

```
const user = (state = {}, action) => {

switch (action.type) {

    case CHECKING_USER:

        return{
            ...state,
            ...action.payload
        };

    case USER_EXIST:

        return {
            ...state,
            ...action.payload
        };
    case USER_NOT_EXIST:

        return {
            ...state,
            ...action.payload
        };

    case USER_CHECKING_ERROR:
        return {
            ...state,
            ...action.payload
        }


    default:
        return state;
 }
};

export default user;
```

in Redux.

This, finally, is the declaration of `PrivateRoute`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


export const PrivateRoute = ({
     isAuthenticated, 
     component: Component, 
     ...rest 
    }) => (

    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
            <div><Component {...props} /></div>
        ) : (
            <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
    )}/>

);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuth
});


export default connect (mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

and `PublicRoute`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


export const PublicRoute = ({
     isAuthenticated, 
     component: Component, 
     ...rest 
    }) => (

    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
            <Redirect to="/" />
        ) : (
            <Component {...props} />
        )
    )}/>

);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuth
});


export default connect (mapStateToProps)(PublicRoute);
```

the mistake is this: when you load, for example, `'/friends'`, it goes before to `Login` component and then to `'/'` so in `Welcome` component. This maybe happens because it renders before `checkUserExist()` is finished.

My question is: is there a way to avoid it? Maybe using a timeout or wait the finish of the ajax call.

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


export const PublicRoute = ({
     isAuthenticated, 
     component: Component, 
     ...rest 
    }) => {

    isAuthenticated ? localStorage.setItem("red", "") : localStorage.setItem(history.location.pathname) ;
    return (<Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
            <Redirect to="/" />
        ) : (
            <Component {...props} />
        )
    )}/>);

};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuth
});


export default connect (mapStateToProps)(PublicRoute);


export const history = createHistory();

class AppContainer extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
    this.props.checkUserExist();
}

redirectMe = () => {
    const redirect= localStorage.getItem("red");
    localStorage.getItem("red", "");
    if(redirect !== "")
        return <Redirect to={redirect} />
}

render() {
    redirectMe()
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Welcome} exact={true}/>
                <PrivateRoute path="/friends"  component={Friends}/>
                <PublicRoute path="/login"  component={Login}/>
                <PrivateRoute path="/loves" component={Loves}/>
                <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

}


  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {    
     checkUserExist: () => dispatch(checkUser())     
    };
};

export default connect(undefined,mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer);
```

What I have done??

I added a condition in private route that if user is not authenticated and private route is looked for the called url is stored in localstorage.

As AppRouter is going to render every time then it will check for localstorage if any url is found it will move to that url and clear local storage.

Note: If this doesnot work then create a variable in the state and connect that state variable in AppRouter.js and instead of setting in localstorage set state there.